# Is it possible to edit sys.messages texts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to add a new language to SQL Server 2008 and edit SQL error messages with message_id less than 50000?

Comment: Messing with any system table (sys.messages is a view, but anyhow) would be a "Bad Idea". Also, note that this is not how error messages are "implemented" [behind the scenes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/08/16/how-it-works-enumeration-of-sys-messages.aspx) - adding a new language doesn't/wouldn't work by adding entries to `sys.messages`.

Comment: For exmple I want to add Persian Language and add sys.messages for error number 18456(Login failed)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible or advisable to edit messages below 50000 in SQL server. You can create user defined messages for ids greater that 50000 using [sp_addmessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178649%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Another possibility is to use [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to return dynamic messages. The message is returned as a server error message to the calling application or to an associated CATCH block of a TRY…CATCH construct.

Answer (score 1):

No, system tables and DMVs cannot be edited. As I understand your needs, you need to handle the exceptions and modify the error messages in client code, for example, when you connect to database.

Answer (score 1):

No. Beside the obvious issue of modifying system tables, actually `sys.messages` has separate issue: messages with `id` below 50000 do *not* come from a table. The built-in system error messages are ordinary [application resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zabda143.aspx). To modify them you would have to modify binaries, and this would be prevented by the [code signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).